# My title is not sitting in my header?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Trying to figure out why my title is so far down on some screens, previous solutions have told me to take away my negative margin when the title was hiding, but now it is too far down. Here is the link:

http://aswanson.net/KiloArt/visions.html

Comment: You might want to use some sort of CSS Rest - On Safari for example, your 'P' tag will have a 1em margin-top by default.

Answer (score 1):

You have `line-height` set to 2.5em, causing the title go down. Change it to 0em to get it back to space.